# Correct way to change #define value within a function in C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, directive

Let say I have a program with multiple functions using the same "define.h" header. There are some defined identifiers I use through the program but for some functions I would like to assign different values to those identifiers. I made up a program as below just to observer:

define.h :

```
#define var 1         //var =1
#define var1 (var+1)  //var1=2
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "define.h"
void function1();
void function2();

using namespace std;
int main(){
    function1(); //call function1
    function2(); // call function2
    return 0;
}
```

function1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "define.h"

#define var 3
using namespace std;

void function1()
{
    cout<<"function1"<<endl;
    cout<<var<<endl;
    cout<<var1<<endl;

}
```

function2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "define.h"

#define var 5                   //redefine var as 5
using namespace std;
void function3();

void function2()
{
    cout<<"function2"<<endl;
    cout<<var<<endl;            //print var which is 5
    cout<<var1<<endl;           
    function3();                // "5" wont be passed onto var in function3
}
```

function3.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "define.h"

using namespace std;

void function3()
{
    cout<<"function3"<<endl;
    cout<<var<<endl;            //function3 use var from define.h , not from function2
    cout<<var1<<endl;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
function1
3
4
function2
5
6
function3
1
2
```

Each function is supposed to print out *var* and *var1* (var1=var+1). What I observed:

1. Function1() is called in main, *var* was re-defined to have value *3* in function1() therefore 3 and 4 were printed out
2. Function2() is called in main, *var* was re-defined to have value *5* in function2() therefore 5 and 6 were printed out
3. In Function2(), Function3() was called but Function3() get *var* from "define.h" instead of using *var*=5 from Function2().
4. If in "define.h"I only *#define var* without  value, all works but Function3() will have an error since *var* does not have a value.

Can you help me to understand this behavior ?

Comment: Macros can be changed only at (pre-)compile time using `#undef` and `#define` again. There's no other way.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace

Comment: Macros are not "passed" anywhere. They work by simple text substitution while a given source file is compiled. Defining a macro in one source file cannot magically affect any other source file. If you want to pass values from one function to another, add parameters to that second function.

Comment: Read about the [C preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor) and the [phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases) from C source code to executable program.